# Catch failure from @Before/AfterMethod in ITestListener

Tags: selenium, testng, allure

I have a test, which fails in @AfterMethod annotation. When it happens, overrided onTestFailure() not called and not perform actions to attach screenshot to allure report.
Is it possible to catch failures from @Before/AfterMethod or @Before/AfterClass in ITestListener or not?

Comment: Try to implement `org.testng.IConfigurationListener` `onConfigurationFailure` methods in advance. If you have some method like `attachScreenshotToAllure()`, you can insert its invocation for all _not-passed_ events in your Listener.

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka Thank you, it works but with error - 
ERROR io.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle - Could not add attachment: no test is running.
Do you have any advices how to add attachment to not running test?

Comment: Now I see the issue more clear. Allure adds some specific since it has its own lifecycle. Seems you have to implement Allure lifecycle listener and override `afterTestStop` method. https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/blob/master/allure-java-commons/src/main/java/io/qameta/allure/listener/TestLifecycleListener.java and then apply your listener like this answer suggests https://stackoverflow.com/a/45693082/5226491.

Comment: See also this https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/issues/419#issuecomment-1015551798

Comment: thank you for help, will check and return with result