# Allure doesn't add attachments within onTestFailure() method?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, allure

I try to add a screenshot to the allure report, at the time when any test is failed. The file is created in the appropriate folder (/allure-results) but the attachment isn't added to the report. Actually, don't pay attention to the screenshot creation - as I determined any attachment isn't added to the report in this (`onTestFailure`) method, which is called each time when any test is fail.

My project structure:

The project is implemented with Cucumber which executes via TestNG.
So the "Cucumber-Step-Class" `DemoTest` extends the Base test that provides the possibility to execute tests from testng.XML file:

```java
@Listeners({TestEventsListener.class})
public class BaseTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }

    @Test(description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void runScenario(PickleWrapper pickleWrapper, FeatureWrapper featureWrapper) {
        TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleWrapper.getPickle());
    }
}
```

the `DemoTest`:

```java
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"classpath:scenarios/demo/demo.feature"},
        glue = "xxx.steps",
        plugin = {"io.qameta.allure.cucumber6jvm.AllureCucumber6Jvm"}

)
public class DemoTest extends BaseTest {

....

    @Given("Open the demo login page")
    public void openTheDemoLoginPage() {
        WebDriver driver = DriverProvider.getInstance().getDriver();
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        Utils.delayMillisec(5000);
        AllureReporter.makeScreenshot(driver); << there is attachment added to the allure report successfully, so this feature is works out of onTestFailure() method
    throw new RuntimeException();// "call" the `TestEventsListener::onTestFailure` method
    }
```

TestEventListener:

```java
public class TestEventsListener implements ITestListener {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        Logging.info("Test failed: " + result); < ----- this log is output, so the method is definitely called
        Allure.addAttachment("Attachment", "Added"); < --- unsuccessful attempt 1
        AllureReporter.makeScreenshot(driver); < ---- unsuccessful attempt 2
    }
```

The main point:

The screenshot is created in the `/allure-results` folder, but not added to the allure as an attachment in the result. So I suppose the test is stopped and allure-results formed before this method is called. I can't figure out why, and how to resolve it (in the simple TestNG project without Cucumber this way works well)

Comment: You probably shouldn't create a new `TestNGCucumberRunner` for every pickle. Have a look at what happens in `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using TestNG listener, but it invokes the method `onTestFailure()` when Allure Test context is already closed, and you can't add attachments anymore.

Try instead to implement Allure Test Listener like below example:

```
public class AllureAttachmentListener implements TestLifecycleListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeTestStop(TestResult result) {
        // Attach your files...
    }
```

In order to register your listener you should create file `io.qameta.allure.listener.TestLifecycleListener` under path `test/resources/META-INF/services`, the content of the file should be your full class path.

For more info see an explanation in the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624859/allure2-listener-to-output-the-steps-in-console)