Appending screenshots or other attachments to steps of Allure report with AOP
I've been researching if it's possible to append screenshots attachments to the specific methods marked by custom @Captured annotation for the Allure reposts using AOP
I created annotation itself and aspect that intercepts marked methods
@Aspect
public class ScreenshotAppenderAspect {

@Pointcut("@annotation(com.annotations.Captured)")
public void captured (){}

//if method returns object
@Around("captured()")
public Object aroundStep(ProceedingJoinPoint point){
    Object result;
    //getting name of allure step
    String stepName = getStepName();
    result = point.proceed();
    
    // method with screenshot attachment
    screenshot(stepName);
    return result;
}

//if it's void method   
@Around("captured() && execution(void *(..))")
public Object aroundStep(ProceedingJoinPoint point){
    
    point.proceed();
    
    // method with screenshot attachment
    Screenshot(stepName);
}}

However the result in report is added Screenshot step after marked with @Captured "open google" step.

Is there way to put Screenshot step or attachment itself directly
at the end inside of marked method as if I did it manually within method itself. I understand allure itself works with AOP but I have limited understanding of its methods

Please, be polite enough to either accept and upvote a given answer or comment on it, if anything is unclear or wrong about it. I asked for a reproducer after you said that my answer was wrong due to your own faulty sample code, which you did not provide. Dmitry Baev wrote a new answer, which you completely ignored too.

Your aspect @Around advice methods never return any results, i.e. nothing is passed on to the caller, which will yield default values like null, 0, false. Besides, I do not see any need to capture the same joinpoint twice. If you write the aspect in the right way, it will also work for void methods. Besides, should the package name not be com.annotations instead of com.annotanions?
Conceptually, your aspect should look like this, plus probably some error handling:
@Aspect
public class ScreenshotAppenderAspect {
  @Around("@annotation(com.annotanions.Captured)")
  public Object aroundStep(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    //getting name of allure step
    String stepName = getStepName();
    Object result = point.proceed();
    // method with screenshot attachment
    Screenshot(stepName);
    return result;
  }
}


Thanks, I did forget to put return statement for the first method. However it still puts screenshot step directly after "open google" step in report not within it.

Then please help me to avoid having wasted my time due to your having multiple problems by publishing a minimal reproducer project on GitHub. I dislike speculating about invisible code.

The order of aspects is specified by the annotation org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclarePrecedence.
Since AspectJ executes after events in the reverse order (the first declared executed last). So, to add screenshots to the steps, you need to declare your aspect after the StepsAspects. This can be done by specifying ScreenshotAppenderAspect to be executed last:
@Aspect
@DeclarePrecedence("*,ScreenshotAppenderAspect")
public class ScreenshotAppenderAspect {
    // ...
}

Additionally, you can improve your aspect by using @After instead of @Around. This can simplify your logic, removing the need to handle exceptions or various return types:
@After(pointcut = "captured()")
public void takeScreenshot() {
    String stepName = getStepName();
    screenshot(stepName);
}

Alternatively, you can use Allure Test Lifecycle Listeners to add screenshots not only to annotated steps but also for the steps created by other integrations & by using Allure Runtime API. For more details, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45693082/3915166.

Your suggested AspectJ solution with @AfterReturning implies that the OP does not want any screenshots taken in case of errors. Probably, they are even more important (for debugging) then, though, don't you think?

In the example provided, exceptions from point.proceed() are not caught, so you'll not get a screenshot in case of an error either.

You can use AfterThrowing together with AfterReturning to process the unsuccessful executions

Then why not just use @After? Why make a simple matter difficult? Besides, in my answer I am mentioning the missing error handling in @Around, if more complex cases need to be handled, such as modifying call parameters or result.

Yes, @After will work. Thanks for pointing it out. Completely overlooked
